# Jquery modal not resizing

Tags: c#, jquery, modal-dialog

Ok,

I have a Jquery DataTable, which has a click event on the first column. The click event, calls a function which in turns calls a C# Webmethod to retrieve data to populate within the dialog.

My problem is that I can't seem to get the modal to resize. I use the followin settings, but it makes no difference.

```
$('#myModal').modal(resizable:true);
```

this is called at the end of the Function. The Method contains sensistive information, so i can't post it's contents, but the frame of the calls are as follows:

```
"fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aoData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
                    if (aoData[11] == 'Duplicate' || aoData[11] == 'Duplicate approved') {
                         $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html('<a class="Main" onclick="ViewDuplicateDetails 
 (\'' + aoData[12] + '\', \'' + aoData[4] + '\',\'' + aoData[0] + '\');">' + aoData[0] + '</a>');

function ViewDuplicateDetail(param1, param2, param3, param4)
{
      AJAX call code to retrieve the data
      success:
        append results to the HTML elements of my dialog (div)
       $('#myModal').modal(resizable:true);

}
```

I dont get the handles to resize, and when the site is display on a screen where the resolution is not high, then the bottom of the modal isn't visible.

***EDIT***
I've included the actually modal, incase there is anything glaringly obvious.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" >
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" 
                    aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 id="ticket-id">Message: <span id="messageRef"></span><span 
                        id="messageType"></span>
                    <span id="checkrecord"></span>
                    <span id="Id"></span>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">

                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="ticket-tabs">
                    <li><a href="#tab5">Record</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab6">Found</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab7">Comments</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab8">Audit</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab5">
                        <div id="1"></div>
                        <div id="2"></div>
                        <div id="3"></div>

                 </div>       
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab6">
                        <div id="results"></div>
                    </div>
                   <div class="tab-pane" id="tab7">

                     <textarea id="txtComments"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab8">
                     <div id="audit"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <span id="txtWarning" style="float:left; color:#ff0000">You must 
                          enter a comment before saving!</span>

                <button id="btnComplete" class="btn btn-danger">Complete</button>
                <button id="btnApprove" class="btn btn-primary">Approve</button>
                <button id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                <button id="btnConfirmComplete" class="btn btn-danger">Confirm 
                 Completion</button>


                  <div id="dowJones" style="text-align:left;">

                      <img src="Media/images/img2.png" width="94" height="20" 
                        alt=""/><br />                      
                  </div>    
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: When you say you can't get the Modal to re-size, does that mean that your modal body scrolls down instead of increasing the height of the modal?

Comment: Would it be possible to create some sort of demonstration in a fiddle to show what is going on?

Comment: I think it can help if you put your css also, if fiddle is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need:

```
$('#myModal').modal({resizable:true});
```

Comment: Nothing. Oddly within my modal i have some tabs running across the top, and within this is a comments field, which has a resize handle. Dragging this resizes the containing modal. However i still don't get any handles to resize the modal per sa

Answer (score 1):

may be this help:

```
$('#myModal').modal(...).resize(function(){/*code on resizing*/});
```

**UPDATE**

try set size for `#myModal` or it part in css in percent

Comment: Nope, no joy. When i resize the browser, the modal bottom goes off the screen, and i can't see it unless i ctrl- the zoom level of the page. I need a way to automatically rezise the modal depending on the view port size

Comment: try set coords and size in percent

Answer (score 1):

`resizable` is not a native option of [Bootstrap's modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage).

If you want to use [jQuery-ui resizable widget](http://jqueryui.com/resizable), you should initialize it using an explicit call :

```
$(function(){
    $('#modal').resizable({ /*resizable options*/ })
});
```

See resizable [examples](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/) and [api doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/).

---

If you want to have the *initial* dialog fit into the screen, you should add some code to check whether the dialogue fits when opened ( `$('#modal').on('shown', function(){ ... })` ), by checking the dialog's dimensions against the viewport dimensions, and adjust it if the dialog falls outside.

Comment: Hi LeGEC, i'm not using the query dialog, but Bootstrap Modal. I have a header, body and footer as listed above. The body contains tabs etc, with buttons at the bottom.

Comment: That's what I say : "resizable" is not an option of bootstrap's moidal. Check the doc.  
If you want to make your dialog resizable, one way to do so is to use jquery-ui's "resizable" widget.